# use regex in gradle template

Tags: regex, file, templates, groovy, expand

I am trying to expand a gradle/groovy template with some properties and that file contains a regex. I need to escape it somehow but I don't want to modify the file. Also I wouldn't like to load file in memory.

I have something like this:

```
<string> ${MY_VAR}</string>
 <string>^[a-zA-Z0-9_.@-]{6,16}$</string>
 <string>((?=.*\d)(?!.*\s)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+~]).{8,12})</string>
 <string> ${MY_VAR}</string>
```

And script

```
copy {
  Properties props = getProps()
  from(source)
  into(dest)
  expand props
}
```

I want  the variables replaced and the regex to remain untouched.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I found that using ReplaceTokens from ant and changing the variables to @MY_VAR@ works. This will be my last solution if there is no other way because if involves changing the file

Answer (score 1):

`expand` uses Groovy's `SimpleTemplateEngine` which means you can use full groovy syntax, but you also have to make sure it works as expected. If it does not work like you want, you can use another method of the `ContentFilterable` interface, e. g. if you do not need fancy Groovy syntax, but always `${<something>}`, something like

```
filter { 
    result = it
    props.each { name, value ->
        result = result.replaceAll("\${$name}", value)
    }
    result
}
```